# Hide common PHP warning and Notices

Tags: php, nginx

**Plot:** First I had a site with GodDaddy, Furstated of their cool CPanel and more cool downtimes I moved on to Digital Ocean VPS.

**Problem:** But when I transferred files to VPS I get some common/uncommon PHP errors. I seen no errors when using godaddy. A few of them are.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: q in /srv/users/someuser/apps/video/public/config.php on line 7
```

and

```
Notice: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead
```

I am using PHP 5.4 (on nginx , the LEMP install)for now. Any way to hide these errors as my site is working flawlessly even when these errors appear.

Comment: I thought everyone got this question wrong. I think I should have titled this as why I was not getting these errors on godaddy.

Comment: BTW my first downvote, and it's greeted.

Comment: You have several answers below suggesting you should disable error reporting. This is a good idea in production, but you should also fix the problems in development. Your error reporting was probably turned off in your first host, so these errors were still there - just not visible. The SSL issue may be due to a newer version of PHP too.

Comment: +[1] for suggestion but actually I didn't got any of these errors when using shared hosting whether Ipage,bluehost or hostgator.

Comment: And I've explained why that might be (I edited the comment - refresh your page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following on the top of your script

```
 error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: a nice and not so stressful suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of suppressing notices and error messages, I would consider fixing the problems. Might be more work to do for now, but I think it's worth the effort in order to have a full running and functioning program in the end - and if Digital Ocean updates libraries your code will break.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: q in /srv/users/someuser/apps/video/public/config.php on line 7
```

this notice tells you that there is a variable not set and in which file and in which line. So you should just go to this file, have a look on what is happening in line 7 and try to fix it. It looks like $q isn't needed at all, so try to comment the line out or take a deeper look in your file if the variable is needed elsewhere.

```
Notice: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead
```

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST with value 1 is deprecated and will be removed as of libcurl 7.28.1. It is recommended to use value 2 instead.

Consider having a look in the file you are running curl and change the line from either

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => true or  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1
```

to:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
```

Looks like GoDaddy used outdated (older) versions of the different libraries.

The curlopt setting may be a warning right now, but will break your program as soon as Digital Ocean updates their libraries or you update them.

Comment: ya godaddy gave a lot of reasons to move and this is one more.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt the answer you accepted is not the right thing to do! Fix the errors, your code will break as soon as Digital Ocean updates curl libraries!

Comment: at least, change the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 2 @IdidntKnewIt

Comment: Its me myself who installs each and everything, its on me BTW yes your solution is a better approach ↑ for that.
Done that CURL thing already

Comment: I think it is. The error messages are there for a reason... I wouldn't want to use outdated libs only because you can't update them anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your php.ini file according to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and avoid the error :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

This will remove notices and coding standards warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file, there are two variables for you consider.  The first one is for the level of errors captured, and the second is whether or not to show them on the screen.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

display_errors = Off
```

Adjusting these will give you the desired output.